# Extract R^2 from quantile regression / summary()

Tags: r, quantile, quantreg

I am using the `quantreg` package to run the following quantile regression in R:

```
bank <-rq(gekX~laggekVIXclose+laggekliquidityspread+lagdiffthreeMTBILL+
lagdiffslopeyieldcurve+lagdiffcreditspread+laggekSPret, tau=0.99)
```

and extract the coefficients and the summary statistic via

```
bank$coefficients
summary(bank)
```

The results I get, are

```
Call: rq(formula = gekX ~ laggekVIXclose + laggekliquidityspread + 
lagdiffthreeMTBILL + lagdiffslopeyieldcurve + lagdiffcreditspread + 
laggekSPret, tau = 0.99)

tau: [1] 0.99

Coefficients:
                       Value    Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)            -0.03005  0.01018   -2.95124  0.00319
laggekVIXclose          0.00471  0.00069    6.81515  0.00000
laggekliquidityspread  -0.01295  0.01619   -0.79976  0.42392
lagdiffthreeMTBILL     -0.12273  0.12016   -1.02136  0.30717
lagdiffslopeyieldcurve -0.13100  0.06457   -2.02876  0.04258
lagdiffcreditspread    -0.21198  0.15659   -1.35377  0.17592
laggekSPret            -0.01205  0.46559   -0.02588  0.97936
```

However, I would like to know the R^2/adjusted R^2 - which the `summary()`-command seems to deliver for simple OLS regressions, but not in case of quantile regressions.

Does anybody know, how to extract them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In quantile regression, you don't have R-squared or adjusted R-squared. It's only pseudo R squared and is not reported in `rq` as you would expect when you use `summary` in `lm`, but you can compute it as follows after estimation of the model bank.

```
rho <- function(u,tau=.5)u*(tau - (u < 0))
V <- sum(rho(bank$resid, bank$tau))
```

This is the answer provided by the author of the package "quantreg" [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-August/110386.html)

Comment: @Metrics This calculates only half of the pseudo-R^2 ingredients.

Answer (score 11):

The pseudo-R^2 measure suggested by Koenker and Machado's 1999 JASA paper measures goodness of fit by comparing the sum of weighted deviations for the model of interest with the same sum from a model in which only the intercept appears.

Here's an example in R:

```
library(quantreg)
data(engel)

fit0 <- rq(foodexp~1,tau=0.9,data=engel)
fit1 <- rq(foodexp~income,tau=0.9,data=engel)

rho <- function(u,tau=.5)u*(tau - (u < 0))
R1 <- 1 - fit1$rho/fit0$rho
```

The code in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19862462/1187671) only gives you the numerator of that fraction.

Comment: Could you please explain the function used for generating "rho"? Why tau=0.5 is used in there?

Comment: @Enigma Sorry for the delayed response. The default is to use median (tau=0.5) as the default since that is the default in rq() and is often omitted. There is more info in [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129246/7071).